# Creating UIView with BG Image and then drawing on top

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, background-image

what I am trying to do is to have an image on which I then want to draw something by overriding the `drawRect` function. Essentially I am trying to create dice, where I use a background and then have the relevant dots drawn in depending on the number selected.

I created the dice dots in **PaintCode** [paint-code](/questions/tagged/paint-code)  and then exported that to use in Xcode (Swift).

I am creating a UIView on Storyboard that I then want to add a background image to and then draw the dots based on the number I pass it.

On it's own the drawing of the dots are working fine, but when I try and add an Image using a subview with UIImageView the image doesn't show up, the background of the UIView is white and even setting it to clearColor() doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: add your imageView code

Comment: Yes. We need the code to help you.

Comment: Apologies, after struggling for a bit I eventually got it sorted when I returned to my code. What I did: I added the following in my UIView before I drew the rest '//// Image Declarations
        let goldDice = UIImage(named: "GoldDice")
        goldDice?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))'